# Moving things around properly with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, positioning, middleman

I'm taking a code test which is a mockup of a psd file which I've never done before. I'm having issues with moving things around and my main experience is in backend with Ruby and Ruby on Rails framework so this is a little new for me.

I need help moving the phone number next to the phone icon. I'm using middleman app framework.

```
    @charset "utf-8";
@import "normalize";

body {
  background: #white;
  font-family: "Lato", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
   text-decoration: none;
}

.border{
   position:relative;
}
.border:hover::after{
   content:'';
   position:absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 0;
   left:0;
   bottom: -1px; /*Change this to increase/decrease distance*/
   border-bottom: 4px solid #FFA500;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul li {
  float: right;
  width: 10%;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: 8px 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -10em;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueLTCom Hv";
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.logo img {
  height: 100;
  width: 90;
  margin-left: 4.4em;
  margin-top: .5em;
}

.navlogo img {
  margin-left: 5em;
  margin-top: 5em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.socialicons {
 margin-left: 73.5em;
 margin-top: -32.3em;
 }

 .phone img{
   margin-left: 62em;
   margin-top: -9em;
   margin-bottom: 12em;

 }

 h4 {
   margin-left: 55em;

   margin-top: 11.6em;
   font-family: "HelveticaNeueLTCom Hv";
   font-size: 20px;
 }

 .mt h1 {
  color: #000000;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 12em;
  font-family: Helvetica regular;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.doc {
  margin: 3em 0;
  font-family: "Lato", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 300;

  a {
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 0.75em 0.7em;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.1s linear;
    &:hover {
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      color: white;
      transition: all 0.15s linear;
    }
  }
}

.welcome {
  -webkit-animation-name: welcome;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .9s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes welcome {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
   -webkit-transform: scale(0);
   opacity: 0;
  }
  82.5% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.03);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

HTML IS HERE

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

   <meta name="Author" content="Keith R. Bachand"/>
   <meta name="Keywords" content="Keith Bachand, Speed Digital"/>
   <meta name="Description" content="Speed Digital Mockup"/>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Speed Digital Mockup</title>
</head>
<!--NAVBAR START-->
<div class="navlogo">
<%= image_tag "sdlogo.png" %>
</div>
<div class="phone">
<%= image_tag "phone.jpg" %>
</div>

<h4>800-900-9090</h4>

<div class="socialicons">
  <%= link_to image_tag("facebookicon.png"), "https://www.facebook.com/speeddigitalusa/" %>
  <%= link_to image_tag("youtubeicon.png"), "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChY6iAIh9waeZ6EGAhuoAVQ" %>
  <%= link_to image_tag("twittericon.png"), "https://twitter.com/speeddigitalusa" %>
</div>

<nav>
   <ul>
       <li><a class="border" href="#">CONTACT</a>
       </li>
       <li><a class="border" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
       </li>
       <li><a class="border" href="#">CAR FINDER</a>
       </li>
       <li><a class="border" href="#">SERVICES</a>
       </li>
       <li><a class="border" href="#">INVENTORY</a>
       </li>
       <li><a class="border" href="#">HOME</a>
       </li>
   </ul>
</nav>

<!--NAVBAR END-->
<body>

<div class="welcome">
<div class="logo">
    <%= image_tag "mainimg.png" %>
</div>
<div class="mt">
  <h1>MODERN TECHNOLOGY</h1>
</div>
  <div class="cp">
  <h3>FUELED BY CLASSIC PASSION</h3>
</div>
  <p class="doc">
    <%= link_to "LEARN MORE >", "https://speeddigital.com", target: "_blank" %>
  </p><!-- .doc -->
</div><!-- .welcome -->
```

Comment: Did you try using `float` or `display:inline-block` in your CSS?

Comment: I didn't but will try that and see if that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the Middleman part, but from guessing at the layout, I would try something like this.

```
<style>
.inline {
    display: inline-block;
}
h4 {
   /*margin-left: 55em;*/
   /*margin-top: 11.6em;*/
   font-family: "HelveticaNeueLTCom Hv";
   font-size: 20px;
 }
</style>

<div class="phone">
    <%= image_tag "phone.jpg" %>
    <h4 class="inline">800-900-9090</h4>
</div>
```

This will put the img and h4 inline, then you could position the margin, width, whatever...

If you make an example without the Middleman I could better help.